# Non-null invalid context error when creating a UIImage from a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, cgcontext

I'm using the following to generate a UIImage from a UIView

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

which usually works but about half the time, I get this error when renderInContext is called:

```
<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x84d0b20
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens or how to even detect when it happens? I think I would feel better if the address for the context was 0x0 because it would at least be something I could test for and deal with but this so far this has me stumped.

Edit: Whoops. Meant to use view.frame.size and not view.bounds.size.

Comment: have you figured this out? I am also getting non-null invalid context error... the UIImage I got out from `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` looks fine though...

Comment: Sadly, no. I think I'm going to have to resort to re-drawing the thing I'm trying to capture with drawing commands.

Comment: @minovsky I got the same issue with context however my situation was a little bit different. Anyway in my case it was a problem with UIGraphicsPushContext/UIGraphicsPopContext balance. I've popped more than pushed and when I was trying to perform any operation on that context (even it was pushed just before using) - Invalid Context error appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue but was able to solve it by pushing and popping the image context prior to my layer rendering its contents.

Try something like this:

```
UIImage *snapshotImage = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, view.layer.contentsScale);
{
    CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (imageContext != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(imageContext);
        {
            [view.layer renderInContext:imageContext];
        }
        UIGraphicsPopContext();
    }

    snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

For what it's worth, there are alternative (and more efficient) ways to obtain a snapshot but it's still under NDA.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept this answer since you've actually seen the issue and have a work-around. I assume the alternatives are under iOS 7? I was hitting this bug under iOS 5 but ultimately worked around it by drawing everything by hand using CoreGraphics.

Comment: Yeah. If you have access to iOS7 documentation, check out some of the new methods added to UIView :)

Comment: Cool! It works for me too. But can somebody explain why does it work?

Answer (score 6):

If you create a context with width or height zero, the context will be invalid.  This could happen if the view size is zero on either axis, *or* if the view is `nil`.

Also, since you're rendering a layer, you might want to get the *layer* bounds and scale, instead of the *view bounds* and *screen scale*.  Most of the time these values will be the same, but it's good to allow for the times they are not.

```
// Debugging output to see how if an invalid context is being created due to zero size.
NSLog(@"View = %@", view);
NSLog(@"View size = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(view.bounds.size));

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.layer.bounds.size, YES, view.layer.contentsScale);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I'll try that out. There's actually a mistake in the code I have posted; I'm actually using view.frame.size and not bounds. I'll try the layer bounds, though. I know the view and dimensions are valid as I have code that prints out their values. The other thing too is that this doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: If you're sending valid arguments to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, the problem is probably outside this code.  It is possible to corrupt the graphics state in ways that only become visible after the damage is done.  Have you seen [invalid context error when drawing a UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7642731/1318452), where someone suggests that calls to `CGContextSaveGState` may cause it, and where the problem turns out to be a `CALayer` that wasn't needed anyway?

Comment: Also, are you calling this on the main thread?  The [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) specifies that it can't be called anywhere else.

Comment: This is being called on the main thread. I don't think it's something outside of that routine that's screwing things up as it's a pretty simple app (TC-Stats in the App Store, if you're into statistical analysis). I don't really do anything weird with UIViews and stuff. Really, what the code is for is for exporting an existing view (such as a UITableView) as a PNG file.

Comment: Do you happen to draw that PNG file anywhere afterward?  When I intentionally construct an invalid context and tell a layer to `renderInContext`, I get dozens of **invalid context** errors, starting with one from `CGContextSaveGState`.  Do you just get a single error from `CGContextDrawImage`?  As an experiment, try creating an invalid context at this point (use `CGSizeZero` instead of the correct size).  You should get **invalid context** errors, but do they come from the same source?

Comment: PNG file gets saved to a file; it's never displayed. I only get the single error. If I intentionally create an invalid context with a zero size, I get a lot of errors because the context is nil. That's really the other part of the problem.

Comment: Are you intentionally adding any images to the table or its cells?  Since your error appears from `CGContextDrawImage`, when other `CGContext...` functions apparently do work, the problem could actually be that the image being drawn is in some way incompatible with the context.  (However, even if you aren't adding images, the table itself might be, especially if you're using accessory views.)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope, this will help you....

Comment: It happen when you release current graphics context reference.If you make Context like `CGContextRef Context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` than you should not release `Context` and if you want release it than use CGBitmapContextCreate for creating context otherwise it will always gives you `<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x84d0b20`

Comment: I don't have any code that releases the context apart from UIGraphicsEndImageContext. Are you saying I should use CGBitmapContextCreate instead and explicitly release it when I'm done?

Comment: yes,But this code also working fine for me...i am getting screenshot at run time..

Comment: Yes, I do too but sometimes, I get the invalid context error and that is ultimately what I'm trying to track down.

Comment: @Vince ; I suggest you to show some more code..May be error is coming because of other things..