# CGRectMake doens't work in UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have this code in my TabBarItem:

```
MeuPrimeiroViewController *primeiro = [[MeuPrimeiroViewController alloc] init];
    MeuSegundoViewController *segundo = [[MeuSegundoViewController alloc]init];

    UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    tabbar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:primeiro,segundo, nil];

    primeiro.tabBarItem.title = @"Primeiro";

    UIImage *images = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    [images drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

    primeiro.tabBarItem.image = images;
    segundo.tabBarItem.title = @"Segundo";
    segundo.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"];
```

And the CGRectMake doens't work, and the console give me a messange:

> Mar  3 20:17:04 MacBook-Pro-de-William.local UITabBarController[1174]
>   : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>   Mar  3 20:17:04 MacBook-Pro-de-William.local UITabBarController[1174]
>   : CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>   Mar  3 20:17:04 MacBook-Pro-de-William.local UITabBarController[1174]
>   : CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>   Mar  3 20:17:04 MacBook-Pro-de-William.local UITabBarController[1174]
>   : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>   Mar  3 20:17:04 MacBook-Pro-de-William.local UITabBarController[1174]
>   : CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>   Mar  3 20:17:04 MacBook-Pro-de-William.local UITabBarController[1174]
>   : CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>   Mar  3 20:17:04 MacBook-Pro-de-William.local UITabBarController[1174]
>   : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a
>   serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
>   invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
>   of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is that method?  Unless it's within `UIView drawRect:` or some such, you shouldn't be calling `[UIImage drawInRect:]` there.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642731/invalid-context-error-when-drawing-a-uiimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CGRectMake` works fine. Your problem is that you're trying to draw an image into a context that doesn't exist. Calling `drawInRect:` draws the image into the current context, and you don't have one (because you didn't create on / your code isn't running in `drawRect:`).

Your line calling `drawInRect:` doesn't look to be required so delete it. And consider what you were trying to achieve with that line.